# upgrade rxjs 6 to 7 lead to typescript errors

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

app starting point versions:

- angular: 11.2.14
- typescript: 4.0.7
- rxjs: 6.X

I wanted to update rxjs library to the latest version(7.1.0), so I did npm install rxjs@latest and then running ng serve. then I got many errors, looks like a typescript issue.
example here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6dHW.png

There is a way to solve it without giving a type to every rxjs operation returning value?
(worked ok without giving types with rxjs 6)

Comment: Angular doesn’t support rxjs 7 yet as far as I know, stick to rxjs 6 , until official support.

Comment: on top of what @waseemrakab said, it is always better to employ the `ng update` command first, rather than go the manual route.

Comment: And on top of that, RxJS v7 has a minimum TypeScript version of 4.2.

Comment: @waseemrakab mentioned support request https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41897

Answer (score 2):

In #RxJS v7.2.0, all operators are exported from `rxjs`. Importing from `rxjs/operators` will be deprecated soon.

Below is the script I wrote to help you with the migration.

You can migrate now, and forbid the import using eslint.

Down pointing backhand indexDown pointing backhand index Magic wand

```
`npx bye-bye-rx-operators-path`
```